# PhantomJs Arabic font missing boxes are coming on jpg file

Tags: phantomjs

Hi I am trying to take screenshot of a Google page with Arabic keywords using phantom js but on jpeg image Arabic font is missing, boxes are coming instead.

Phantomjs version - 1.9.7

Centos 6.5

Answer (score 0):

## Steps I followed to solve this

### 1. Checked if Arabic Support is available:

```
yum grouplist
```

### 2. Then if available install arabic support:

```
yum groupinstall 'Arabic Support'
```

This solved the issue.